# getting error while creating maven project, org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I have downloaded a eclipse mars for javaEE developers from site. After installed, I am creating maven project in javaEE perspective. While creating in select an archetype, `org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes`, which was not registered so I registered by clicking on add archetype by giving groupId,a rtifactId and version. Then clicking on finish I get below error

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war- plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read   artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.2

yes I did some search on these error, saying to check maven repository server, which is up, and checking for `settings.xml` file but how do I do this and `settings.xml` file is not visible in my `.m2` folder. 
Please give me some suggestion on this.

Comment: there is no settings.xml page, it is a file, and it is not located under the .m2 maven local cache but under MAVEN_HOME/conf, so you need to check in your Maven installation folder